# %d format: a number is required, not NoneType for is_valid()

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to call is_valid() on a ModelForm that I created and for some reason it is giving the exception:

```
TypeError at /submit/
%d format: a number is required, not NoneType
```

The view in question is this:

```
def submitted_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        test = PickUserForm(request.POST)
        if test.is_valid():
            print "test"
            test.save()
    return HttpResponse("File uploaded.")
```

which connects with this ModelForm:

```
class PickUserForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Submission
        widgets = {
            'comment' : Textarea(attrs={'cols':80, 'rows':20}),
        }
        fields = ['p1_name', 'p2_name', 'p1_url', 'p2_url', 'p1_uid', 'p2_uid', 'p1_subregion', 'p2_subregion', 'comment', 'hacker', 'file']
```

The Submission model is fairly simple:

```
class Submission(models.Model):
    p1_name = models.CharField()
    p2_name = models.CharField()
    p1_url = models.CharField()
    p2_url = models.CharField()
    p1_uid = models.IntegerField()
    p2_uid = models.IntegerField()
    p1_subregion = models.IntegerField()
    p2_subregion = models.IntegerField()
    comment = models.CharField()
    hacker = models.CharField()
    file = models.CharField()
```

The stacktrace isn't very helpful and points to `functional.py in __mod__, line 160`.  I've checked that line of code out, but can't make sense of it.  The other parts of the stacktrace are:

```
Traceback:
115. response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
44. if test.is_valid():
```

I've poked around the POST data that came with the stacktrace, and didn't see anything out of the ordinary, so I don't understand where this NoneType is coming from.  One thing to note is that "File uploaded" is a bit misleading since I'm carrying over the file upload data from another form, which is why I only pass in request.POST and not request.FILES as well.

edit: full stacktrace:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/submit/

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/<project_dir>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args,     **callback_kwargs)
File "/<project_dir>/views.py" in submitted_file
  44.       if test.is_valid():
File "/<project_dir>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in     is_valid
  126.         return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
File "/<project_dir>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in     _get_errors
  117.             self.full_clean()
File "/<project_dir>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in     full_clean
  274.         self._post_clean()
File "/<project_dir>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in     _post_clean
  332.             self.instance.clean_fields(exclude=exclude)
File "/<project_dir>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in     clean_fields
  946.                 setattr(self, f.attname, f.clean(raw_value, self))
File "/<project_dir>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields    /__init__.py" in clean
  213.         self.run_validators(value)
File "/<project_dir>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields    /__init__.py" in run_validators
  165.                 v(value)
File "/<project_dir>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/validators.py" in     __call__
  168.                 self.message % params,
File "/<project_dir>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in     __mod__
  160.                 return six.text_type(self) % rhs

Exception Type: TypeError at /submit/
Exception Value: %d format: a number is required, not NoneType
```

edit2: forgot the main yellow part:

```
TypeError at /submit/

%d format: a number is required, not NoneType

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/submit/
Django Version:     1.5.1
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

%d format: a number is required, not NoneType

Exception Location:     <project_dir>/local/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/django/utils/functional.py in __mod__, line 160
Python Executable:  <project_dir>/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.3
Python Path:    

['<project_dir>',
 '<project_dir>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-    0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
 '<project_dir>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-    py2.7.egg',
 '/home/trevor/django_projects/SC2Hackers/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-    py2.7.egg',
 '<project_dir>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-    py2.7.egg',
 '<project_dir>/lib/python2.7',
 '<project_dir>/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '<project_dir>/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '<project_dir>/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '<project_dir>/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '<project_dir>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '<project_dir>/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

Server time:    Wed, 5 Jun 2013 19:23:31 -0500
```

Comment: can you show your actual model ? This model wont compile the way it is . Also, what is functional.py? Is it part of a library ?

Comment: @karthikr What do you mean my actual model?  That is it.  I have no idea what functional.py is, it's part of Django.

Comment: Can you include a normal Python formatted version of the stack trace? Also, what version of Django and Python are you using?

Comment: @DavidK.Hess I just edited the post.

Comment: It appears to be blowing up trying to generate a validation failed message for an attribute of your model. It appears something somewhere has added a validator to your model but with a limit_value of None. Are you sure the Submission model you've shown here is really the one that code is using?

Comment: @trevor-e I mean to say that these models would not validate because `CharField` does not have max_length, etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CharField) max_length is a required argument for CharField.

Hence, adding the max_length to the CharField should fix it.

I just had the same issue while adding a new Model and ModelForm, based on a preexisting Form, to an application in a Django 1.4 project. I had not used max_length in the Form (which worked without any issues) and since CharField is common to Form and Model, I tried using the field as it is. Kaboom!

Fortunately, I noticed the word 'required' in the documentation. The error message and traceback were not very helpful.

Comment: The error message and traceback weren't helpful at all. Seems like they should have a more specific error for when a required argument is missing. Or am I missing something?